# Google maps displaying jibberish

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

my map is not rendering correctly.

[image: Jibberish map]

I have never experienced this yet (notice the icons on the right buttons being distorted). The code used to generate the map is extremely simple:

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 43.828430, lng: 18.3445995},
            zoom: 18
        });

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 43.828430, lng: 18.3445995},
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9zhNUfid1PgR6FZ-g8xTp_NCqV3JvsHM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was that I had a bad CSS rule that was interfering with google's rendering.

For reference it was 100% max width on img.

Answer (score 1):

Idk why, but when I tried your code, it worked but the map was also gray. When I pointed `style="width:500px;height:500px"` map become working

Comment: A div containing the map **must have a specified width/ height**